# Behavior of operator[] on 1D and 2D arrays in C++ AMP.

Tags: multithreading, multidimensional-array, concurrency, parallel-processing, c++-amp

I've enocuntered a very strange exception when writting code in C++Amp. I define two concurrency::array objects as follows:

```
concurrency::array<float, 2> img_amp_data(11, 11, image_data.begin()); 
concurrency::array<float> a_amp_result(121, empty_vec.begin());
```

When I want to access the elements of the first of them

```
std::cout << img_amp_data[0][0] << std::endl;
```

everything runs properly, but when I want to access the second one

```
std::cout << a_amp_result[0] << std::endl;
```

I get a following exception:

> Exception: (The array is not accessible on CPU)

It is a very odd situatuon because I can access 2+ dimensional arrays and it is forbidden to access only one dimensional array? 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into a syntax quirk.

For an `array` of rank larger than 1, `operator[]` with integral parameter returns an `array_view` referring to the slice of the original `array`. The subsequent `operator[]` operates on the `array_view` object, which is allowed on the host -- and in your case causes an implicit data copy before returning a reference to the element.

For an `array` of rank 1 `operator[]` with integral parameter, or `operator[]` with `index` parameter for any `array`, return a reference to the element. Both are allowed only on the location where the `array` is resident - by default it is the default `accelerator_view`, however you can request to create the `array` in the CPU memory as well.

Unless you want to have fine-grained control on the data movement between the host and the `accelerator_view`, it is suggested to use the `array_view` type ubiquitously.