# Is it safe to modify elements of std::valarray<T> concurrently?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, valarray

If I've understood correctly, since C++11 it has been safe to call const member functions of a container concurrently and modify the elements of a container as long as the container itself is not modified as part of the operation (as seen from e.g. the table concerning thread safety in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)). Since std::valarray is not listed in the containers section of the (draft) standard, I'm unsure if thread safety also applies to it. In other words,

- Is it safe to read from a std::valarray concurrently (in particular by using operator[] with slices)?
- Is it safe to modify the elements of std::valarray<T> concurrently if the operation on T is safe?

I would like to use std::valarray for a multidimensional array of numbers that would be filled using multiple threads.

Comment: `std::valarray` is really an orphan in the container family. I doubt to many people use it.

Comment: In this question’s example it’s working in thread safe way, also your link is not opening.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21147991/3254405

Comment: My mistake, someone fixed the link. I would like to use the standard library instead of C++ AMP if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, [`[res.on.data.races]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.data.races) protects *distinct slices* from participating in data races, under

> A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly
>   access objects accessible by threads other than the current thread
>   unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the
>   function's arguments, including `this`.

[`[container.requirements.dataraces]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.dataraces) adds extra protection around modifications to distinct elements, which strictly `valarray` lacks.